# Image Downloader won't download all the images links

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am working on a project that requires me to auto-download images from a basic websearch. I've created this script which should be downloading all the images it finds, except the script isn't working as intended. I have consulted various forms and tutorials but non seem to have the fix.

```
from bs4 import beutifulsoup, requests

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
image = soup.find_all("img")

for img in image:
    name = img['alt']
    link = img['src']

    with open(name.replace(" ", "-").replace("/", "") + ".jpg", "wb") as f:`
        im = requests.get(link)
        f.write(im.content)
```

If I print the img links, it shows all the images which can be downloaded, but for some reason it downloads 1-2 images then stops. Not to mention the downloaded images are further down the list of links.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, you can append the links to a list, then download the images via the iterating list of urls

```
list_of_urls = []

for img in image:
     link = img["src"]
     list_of_urls.append(link)

for link in list_of_urls:
     with open(str(list_of_urls.index(link)) + ".jpg", "wb") as f:
          f.write(requests.get(link).content)
```